# Logging into server (ssh) with bash script

Tags: bash, logging, ssh, server

I want to log into server based on user's choice so I wrote bash script. I am totally newbie - it is my first bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Where to log?\n  1. Server A\n  2. Server B"
read to_log
if [ $to_log -eq 1 ] ; then
    echo `ssh user@ip -p 33`
fi
```

After executing this script I am able to put a password but after nothing happens.

If someone could help me solve this problem, I would be grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: If you do `ssh user@ip -p 33` instead of `echo \`ssh user@ip -p 33\`` , does it do what you want then?

Comment: Are you able to login into the server normally without the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this script is the contents of the `if` statement. Replace:

```
echo `ssh user@ip -p 33`
```

with

```
ssh user@ip
```

and you should be good. Here is why:

Firstly, the use of back ticks is called "command substitution". Back ticks have been deprecated in favor of `$()`.

Command substitution tells the shell to create a sub-shell, execute the enclosed command, and capture the output for assignment/use elsewhere in the script. For example:

`name=$(whoami)`

will run the command `whoami`, and assign the output to the variable `name`.

the enclosed command has to run to completion before the assignment can take place, and during that time the shell is capturing the output, so nothing will display on the screen.

In your script, the `echo` command will not display anything until the `ssh` command has completed (i.e. the sub-shell has exited), which never happens because the user does not know what is happening.

You have no need to capture the output of the `ssh` command, so there is no need to use command substitution. Just run the command as you would any other command in the script.